# Unlearn incorrect substitution

Tags: macos, autocorrect

Recently my MacBook started correcting "Firstname Lastname" (with my actual name) with "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME" automatically, and it is getting infuriating. It looses accents as well.

I have deleted my personal dictionary (and everything in `~/Library/Spelling`). There is no related substitution added manually in the settings, and I can't add one since it only happens on the two-words group.

This is really bothering me as signing my name on emails often ends up in having an erroneous signature sent. What can I try ?

Comment: What program/application is the behavior happening in? It could be an application-specific problem.

Comment: @agarza it happens in multiple apps (most of those that enable autocorrect, e.g. TextEdit, Notes, Airmail, Discord,...)